# Error in multicasting a message in java

Tags: java, sockets, multicast, multicastsocket

I need to multicast a message across connected clients but facing a problem. I have tried the following snippet for [this](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html) link:

```
String msg = "Hello";
InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("228.5.6.7");
MulticastSocket s = new MulticastSocket(6789);
s.joinGroup(group);
DatagramPacket hi = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.length(),
                         group, 6789);
s.send(hi);
```

I am getting an exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Not a multicast address
```

I tried:

- localhost
- 127.0.0.1
- 192.168.1.29(my local ip)

What could have gone wrong. Being new to this topic i am unable to debug it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: s.joinGroup(group) is this not the correct command?

Comment: @publ1c_stat1c There is no such operation as 'set[ting] up a multicast group'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me.

You don't need to join a group to send to it. Only to receive from it. However if you do join it, you need to specify an IP address that is a valid multicast address. Despite what it says in the code you posted, clearly your *actual* code doesn't use a valid multicast address.

Comment: it worked now but it works only between two connections only. Is it possible to make it work for one to many connections?

Comment: Eh? Multicast *is* one to many. You can have as many group members as you like. All they have to do is join the group and receive.